# Файл js закодировался в 16ти ричный и больше не открывается visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, tfs

Доброго времени суток. Проблема вот в чём, жил был файл js в командном проекте visual studio TFS, и вдруг захожу утром в vs, а файл перестал открыватся в редакторе visual studio, открыл в sublime-text 3, а код файла оказывается превратился в 16тиричный. Почему так произошло и как это исправить?

Comment: Может у вас троян файлы пошифровал. Или файловая система побилась...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не знаю, что это было, помог откат до предыдущей версии